# How to add table css in highmap tooltips

Tags: css

tooltip: {
headerFormat: '',
pointFormatter: function() {
let txt = `<tr  style="border: 1px solid red;"><td>DATA1</td></tr>`
txt += `<tr  style="border: 1px solid red;"><td>DATA1</td></tr>`
return txt
},
footerFormat: '',
shared: true,
useHTML: true
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.